# Passing the Data Argument in R User Defined Functions

Tags: r, function, arguments, user-defined-functions

For functions like `lm()` in R, you pass the "data" argument into the function, usually a dataframe, and then R knows all of the columns by name rather than referencing them. So the difference being `x=column` instead of referencing in the fashion `x=df$column`. So how can I use that same method in my own user defined functions?

A simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x=1:100,y=x*(1+rnorm(n=100)))

test_corr <- function(x,y) {
  cor(x,y) %>% return()
}

# Right now I would do this
test_corr(df$x,df$y)

# I want to be able to do this
test_corr(data=df, x, y)
```

Comment: Could you make an example of the type of function you have in mind and how you want to call it?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @camille thank you for your feedback, I have attached an example of what I am looking for.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for your feedback, I have attached an example of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `tidyverse` functions, it would make sense to use tidy evaulation for this type of task. For this function you could do

```
test_corr <- function(data, x, y) {
  quo( cor({{x}}, {{y}}) ) %>% 
    rlang::eval_tidy(data=data)
}

test_corr(df, x, y)
```

First we make a quosure to build the expression you want to evaluate and we use the `{{ }}` (embrace) syntax to insert the variable names you pass in to the function into the expression. We then evaluate that quosure in the context of the data.frame you supply with `eval_tidy`.

You might also be interested in the [tidyselect](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyselect/vignettes/tidyselect.html) package vignette where more options are discussed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reformulate`

```
apply_fun <- function(response, terms, data) {
   lm(reformulate(terms, response), data)
}

apply_fun("mpg", "cyl", mtcars)
#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate(terms, response), data = data)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          cyl  
#     37.885       -2.876  

apply_fun("mpg", c("cyl", "am"), mtcars)

#Call:
#lm(formula = reformulate(terms, response), data = data)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          cyl           am  
#     34.522       -2.501        2.567
```